# Protractor e2e testing to find text

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am doing e2e testing using protractor for my Angular application.
This is my code

```
<input type="button" value='Add New Record'/>
<table class="table table-striped s10 ng-scope">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Appt Time</th>
            <th>Tag</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>12:30AM</td>
            <td><input type="button" value='Add Tag'/></td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Alice</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>10:10AM</td>
             <td><input type="button" value='Add Tag'/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My question is , if I click on 'Add New Record' it will appens a new record to the table. Here I want to test the Name of newly created record and 'Add Tag' button.
I tried below code

```
it('Testing Add New Record', function(){  
    var tbl = element( by.css('.table'));
     var tblrow = tbl.all( by.css('tr')).get(0);
     var tbldata = tblrow.all(by.css('td')).get(0);
          expect(tbldata.getText()).toEqual('Alice');
     var tbldata = tblrow.all(by.css('td')).get(2);
     tbldata.click();
       });
```

It is working. But if I add one more record, we have to change the code each time. So I want to find the text of newly created record and 'Add Tag' button dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to verify that after creating a new record it appears as the last row in the table. In this case, instead of getting it by index, use [`last()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.last):

```
element.all(by.css('table.s10 tr')).last();
```

Comment: Edited my question. Record is inserted based on Appt Time.

Comment: @NNR correct me if I'm wrong, now you need to get the latest row by `Appt Time` time? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for reply @alecxe. Not with Appt Time, I want to get the latest record by Name.

Comment: @NNR Thanks. So, you know that `Alice` name beforehand and you want to find an appropriate row in the table by this name?

Comment: Yes. And one more thing is I want to click on 'Add tag' button of the same row.

Comment: @NNR then you can locate the row by text using `by.xpath`: `by.xpath('//tr[td[1] = "Alice"]/td/input[@value = "Add Tag"]')` - this would point to the button on the appropriate row.

Comment: var button = by.xpath('//tr[td[1] = "Alice"]/td/input[@value = "Add Tag"]');
 button.click();                                                                                                         I am not able to click 'Add Tag' button

Comment: @N123 it should have been the `var button = element(by.xpath('//tr[td[1] = "Alice"]/td/input[@value = "Add Tag"]'));`, right? Have you solved the problem? Thanks!